# Quote received from 0x swap API returns no valid, unsigned transaction?

Tags: web3.py, 0x

I'm trying out the new 0x Fantom integration API, in order to automate some trading tasks.

According to this, using the Swap-API from 0x returns a transaction for a quote, which just needs to be signed & sent to the network: https://0x.org/docs/api#get-swapv1quote , quote:

> Get an easy-to-consume quote for buying or selling any token. The
> return format is a valid unsigned Ethereum transaction and can be
> submitted directly to an Ethereum node to complete the swap.

But when I actually get the result from a (working) quote, the data I receive cannot be treated as unsigned transaction: signing via web3 (Python) complains that there's unrecognized fields.

Sample code:

```
get_quote_url = 'https://fantom.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=DAI&buyToken=WETH&sellAmount=10000000000000000000'
response = requests.get(get_quote_url) 
quote = response.json()
my_sell_DAI_for_WETH_quote['nonce'] = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_address)
w3.eth.account.signTransaction(my_sell_DAI_for_WETH_quote, my_address_privkey)
```

This results in the error:

> "TypeError: Transaction must not include unrecognized fields:
> {'allowanceTarget', 'orders', 'estimatedGas', 'sources',
> 'minimumProtocolFee', 'protocolFee', 'sellTokenToEthRate',
> 'buyTokenToEthRate', 'sellAmount', 'buyAmount', 'guaranteedPrice',
> 'buyTokenAddress', 'price', 'sellTokenAddress'}"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's valid for most javascript web3 libraries, which typically ignore unused fields. YMMV with Python. It looks like you might just need to prune those excess fields.

Comment: Two of the suggested fields it doesnt recognize are:

> 'sellAmount', 'buyAmount',

If I leave them both out, how does it even still know how much to swap?

I think I might be doing something wrong here... thanks, will try anyways

Comment: All of that information is encoded in the `data` field.

Comment: Confirmed, removing the fields lets me sign it.

Ran into other problems still, for which I am unsure what it is: the field "gas", "gasPrice" and "value" are all returned from the 0x API as string, must be converted to integer before it can be signed. The "to" address is a non-checksum-address and must be converted to a checksum-address as well, before signing the transaction works.